# How to find a randomly placed numerical value after a string match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file as follows:

```
GROSS WE GHT
MARKS AND NUMBERS:
PCS:
(KILO):
POW- 40162463
PAF. 128993.1
BOM
1 USTER QUANTUM 3
1.10
VIA MUMBAI
AIRPORT/INDIA
CO210044158
```

Here the output I want is using regex and python print "weight= 1.10 Kilos".

```
import re    
with open('file_new1.txt') as fd:    
for line in fd:    
    match = re.search(r'KILO', line)    
    if match:                
        print('found')
```

I have made the following code to match KILO in the above text file. My question is How do I match the numeric 1.10 after I find string 'KILO'? Please note :

1) 1.10 is sample weight it can also have value of 2322.00 or other integer value

2) 1.10 always occurs after KILO and on a new line

3) String can have value of KILO or KG

Comment: Is it the only pure numerical line after KILO ?

Comment: yes, Its a numerical line after KILO or KG (Ive edited the question)

Comment: I'd suggest a change in title to "How to find a randomly placed numerical value after  a string match".  Is the value always guaranteed to be the *only* numerical line after an occurrence?

Comment: Ive edited the title, yes the value is always guaranteed to be numerical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below loops through the file until it sees a line containing `KILO` or `KG`.  It tries to convert every line after that one to a float, and returns that float when successful

```
def get_weight(fp):
    next(line for line in fp if 'KILO' in line or 'KG' in line)
    for line in fp:
        try:
            return float(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    raise ValueError("No numeric line after 'KILO'")


with open('file_new1.txt') as fd:
    print(get_weight(fd))
    # 1.1
```

The search for `KILO` or `KG` is pretty basic, and prone to false positives.  If you know it will always appear with other characteristics (Surrounded by parentheses, for example), you may want to include those in the search.